# How to check hive query running on amazon EMR or EC2 after getting disconnected from client

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, hive, amazon-emr

I have been facing this problem several times. I ssh to amazon `EC2` or `EMR` machine using the command line and run some `hive` query in interactive mode. Which shows the gradual progress of mapper and reducer phase. But, let's say for some network problem i get disconnected from `EC2` or `EMR` machine. Now, will my `hive` query still be running? If, yes then can i check the progress report like we see on hive console again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, three things you can do:

1. Use the web interface. Amazon gives you access to this as detailed [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-manage-view-web-interfaces.html)
2. Run the query in [screen](https://kb.iu.edu/data/acuy.html) and then if you get disconnected, just reconnect and reattach to your previous session. You can also point the logging to happen to some file instead of stdout so you can then just reopen this when you log back on to the machine
3. Run the query using [nohup](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/) so it's not attached to any session and will keep running on its own even after you get kicked off. Again, pipe all logging to some file rather than stdout and then just check that file or tail it once you log back on.